# Currying in JS: Pass additional variable to callback without changing the callback signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, functional-programming, currying

I'm using AWS S3 API wrapper. To download files from cloud I call the following wrapper:

`aws.s3.downloadFile(bucket, fileName, cbDownloadOk, cbDownloadErr);`

Inside this function we build parameters' container and then call the official AWS S3 API:

```js
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        cbDownloadErr(err); // an error occurred
    } else {
        cbDownloadOk(data); // successful response
    }
});
```

Now I want to be able to print the name of downloaded file, e.g.:

```js
const cbDownloadOk = function (data) {
    console.log("File " + fileName + " downloaded");
}
```

The problem is that I can't change the implementation of wrapper and hence, to change the signature of the `cbDownloadOk` callback.

Is there any way to pass to `cbDownloadOk` the `fileName` without changing the implementation of the wrapper? Is usage of global variable is the only way to do that?

**Update:**
As we can learn from the answer, this question deals with the [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function. You can call it with `filename` and it will give you exactly what you want: a function accepts exactly one parameter, `data`, and has access to the additional parameter (`filename`).

```
const mySuccessCb = filename => data => {
  // data and name are available here
  console.log("File " + filename + " downloaded");
}
```

Usage:

```
aws.s3.downloadFile(myBucket, filename, mySuccessCb(filename), cbDownloadErr);
```

Comment: It worked! Special thanks for the link to the article.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to ensure `cbDownloadOk` is defined in a scope that has access to `fileName`:

```js
aws.s3.downloadFile(
  bucket, 
  fileName, 
  (data) => console.log("File " + fileName + " downloaded"),
  cbDownloadErr
);
```

Or you could pass a function that calls `cbDownloadOk` with `fileName` as an additional parameter:

```js
aws.s3.downloadFile(
  bucket,
  fileName, 
  (data) => cbDownloadOk(data, fileName),
  cbDownloadErr
);
```